# How can I test Google Cloud Storage on its backup & recovery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to demonstrate, by the means of a test, that Google Cloud Storage performs backups of the data, for a case where we have multi multi-region bucket.

- What is the way to achieve this?
- Or what other test could I imagine to demonstrate and implement the backing up of the data on Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

Objects stored in [multi-region buckets are geo-redundant](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#geo-redundant). You would have to be able to simulate large scale regional disruptions.

Comment: How exactly can we simulate this?

Comment: I do not want to be responsible for someone causing a large scale disruption, so put it simply apart from natural disasters, I do not know of any other way to test that.

Comment: @JohnAndrews - Your application cannot see past the Cloud Storage endpoint. To simulate a disaster you would need to simulate failures on the other side of that endpoint. You cannot do that, so your objective to simulate failures cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can always use third-party solutions to provide backup of your data.
Here are some [examples](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine/docs/concepts-backup-vms)s about these solutions.